# Reorder columns in boxplots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this boxplot and I want to reorder the columns. Instead of MAR, MCAR, MNAR, I want MCAR, MAR, MNAR. And the legend is wrong too, orange is ymiss and blue is yobs but I can't change it. Can you help me? thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
logistic <- function(x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))
set.seed(80122)
n <- 300
dt <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = n, mu = c(0, 0),
                   Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), nrow = 2));dt

r2.mcar <- 1 - rbinom(n, 1, 0.5);r2.mcar
r2.mar <- 1 - rbinom(n, 1, logistic(dt[, 1]));r2.mar
r2.mnar <- 1 - rbinom(n, 1, logistic(dt[, 2]));r2.mnar

yobs1<-dt
yobs1[r2.mcar==0,2]<-NA;yobs1
yobs2<-dt
yobs2[r2.mar==0,2]<-NA;yobs2
yobs3<-dt
yobs3[r2.mnar==0,2]<-NA;yobs3

dados<-matrix(cbind(yobs1[,1],yobs2[,1],yobs3[,1],yobs1[,2],yobs2[,2],yobs3[,2]),ncol=1)

v<-c(rep("yobs",900),rep("ymiss",900))
m<-c(rep("MCAR",300),rep("MAR",300),rep("MNAR",300))
dados<-data.frame(v,m,dados)
names(dados)<-c("y", "mecanismo","valores")

p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x =valores, y = mecanismo)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = y), position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightskyblue","lightsalmon"))
p + facet_grid(~mecanismo)
```

[image: boxplot]

Answer (score 1):

Your one question is actually two questions:

1. **Changing the Order of the facets**.  `ggplot2` first changes your data in `dados$mecanismo` to a factor.  The order of the facets are related to the order of the levels of that factor, which by default will often be the order in which they appear in your dataset.  To change the order, you need to define `dados$mecanismo` as a factor in your data frame, then also define the levels in the specific order.
2. **Assigning a specific color in a legend to a factor**.  In your `scale_fill_manual` command, you are assigning `values=`.  By default, the order of the values are applied according to the order of the levels of the factor (which is in this case `dados$y`).  You can just re-specify the levels of that factor, but to assign colors specifically, you don't need to.  All you need to do is supply a `list(..` or a named vector `c('name'='color', 'name2'='color2',..` to `values=` in place of a vector of colors.  Incidentally... you can change the order in which `ymiss` and `yobs` appears in the legend by setting the factor as indicated in #1 above...

Here's the code and plot:

```
# relevel factor for right order of facets
dados$mecanismo <- factor(dados$mecanismo, levels=c('MCAR','MAR','MNAR'))

p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x =valores, y = mecanismo)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = y), position = position_dodge(0.9)) +

  # set colors with named vector
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('yobs'="lightskyblue",'ymiss'="lightsalmon"))
p + facet_grid(~mecanismo)
```

[image]

## EDIT: Change order of legend keys

After some comments, it's clear that the OP was intending not just to recolor the data according to specific values for `ymiss` and `yobs`, but also change the positioning of the boxes in the legend to match that of the plot.  By this, I mean that in the plot above, the boxplot for `yobs` is on top with `ymiss` below, yet in the legend on the right, the order is reversed.  The fix for this is to specify the ordering of labels explicitly through the `breaks=` argument of `scale_fill_manual`.  This addresses and fixes that issue:

```
dados$mecanismo <- factor(dados$mecanismo, levels=c('MCAR','MAR','MNAR'))

ggplot(dados, aes(x =valores, y = mecanismo)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = y), position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  
  # set colors with named vector
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c('yobs'="lightskyblue",'ymiss'="lightsalmon"),
    breaks = c('yobs', 'ymiss')
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's still wrong because the blue boxplots with the outliers must be the orange ones (ymiss). The legend is right, the only problem are the boxplots!

Comment: Seems it matches the same as your original, right?  The boxes on top with outliers are `yobs` for both the original and the modified one.  The order of the legend is different than the order of the boxes though - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. My original has the boxes right, the only thing wrong is the legend! Now the only thing wrong are the boxes!

Comment: Ah - now it is clear.  Yes, there is a simple solution to that, which relates to addressing the `breaks=` argument in `scale_fill_manual`.  Posted the edit in the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother again! I think I wasn't very clear. The ones with outliers are supost to be ymiss not yobs. In your EDIT the legend is right and the boxes are wrong..

Comment: The issue there is the data assignment, then, not the code for the plot.  It seems you have your `ymiss` and `yobs` assignment incorrect when designating `v<-c(rep...`.   It should be ymiss first, then yobs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code and it will work:

```
#Reorder var
dados$mecanismo <- factor(dados$mecanismo,levels = c("MCAR","MAR","MNAR"),ordered = T)

p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x =valores, y = mecanismo)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = y), position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightsalmon","lightskyblue"))
p + facet_grid(~mecanismo)
```

[image]

Comment: @Cláudia123 Great! I see you are working with missing data mechanisms, it is a pretty cool topic. If you feel comfortable with this answer just accept it :)

Comment: The only error now is that the blue one should be the orange one. They are switched. The one that has the outlier is the ymiss so it should be orange

Comment: In such case @Cláudia123 try adding `scale_fill_manual(values = c('yobs'='lightskyblue','ymiss'='lightsalmon'))`