# How to reorder boxplot in a specific order with interactions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, boxplot

My current graph looks:

(My graph is using `wesanderson` Darjeeling1 color palette instead, but everything else is the same.)

[image: Example graph]

which is made using `dput()` from this simplified data.

```
structure(list(Drug = c("Control", "Control", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", 
"Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", 
"Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", 
"Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", "Amlexanox", 
"EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"EPZ", "EPZ", "EPZ", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", 
"Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Itaconate", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", 
"Senicapoc", "Senicapoc", "Senicapoc"), Drugcc = c(0L, 0L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 
250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 
250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 
250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 250L, 250L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Tat = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 60L, 60L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 6L, 6L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 6L, 
6L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L), Cocaine = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), Size = c(83.248, 381.885, 269.677, 273.223, 
201.211, 340.553, 122.723, 144.61, 217.305, 93.801, 374.772, 
124.677, 155.162, 284.553, 250.136, 172.433, 372.077, 465.878, 
702.344, 161.807, 251.308, 769.558, 404.907, 239.974, 215.351, 
476.933, 207.535, 278.455, 933.354, 1400.024, 1192.117, 544.933, 
869.466, 282.966, 105.917, 293.455, 378.721, 725.003, 537.01, 
1182.022, 428.126, 779.281, 703.108, 938.009, 942.795, 399.482, 
903.263, 566.714, 824.148, 808.794, 722.544, 344.975, 611.226, 
253.23, 521.659, 146.835, 350.668, 431.007, 351.482, 373.738, 
372.388, 838.106, 378.873, 422.488, 1004.811, 554.75, 1042.232, 
1099.928, 899.723, 1166.844, 933.377, 539.196, 737.805, 898.327, 
1406.216, 2251.9, 1188.065, 853.86, 680.177, 976.296, 707.894, 
559.336, 1682.795, 1098.931, 295.322, 1637.33, 932.028, 912.885, 
806.202, 1215.784, 515.267, 1106.509, 705.103, 483.362, 450.061, 
1024.752, 294.524, 522.247, 701.314, 364.117, 550.961, 598.42, 
562.527, 279.17, 769.112, 376.133, 557.143, 603.405, 277.354, 
923.566, 669.608, 715.871, 535.208, 293.466, 296.917, 299.433, 
546.774, 307.286, 504.699, 881.578, 963.135, 1453.277, 883.771, 
903.442, 751.166, 1099.392, 306.089, 692.938, 590.244, 792.433, 
1002.922, 1299.099, 1200.922, 917.47, 722.052, 1359.356, 996.236, 
531.618, 349.759, 1469.029, 625.738, 525.437, 680.575, 991.244, 
934.33, 902.344, 1011.932, 1581.096, 892.334, 1100.901, 1106.788, 
722.811, 699.273, 779.266, 1008.411, 992.611, 1022.722, 1033.322, 
934.811, 1134.844, 596.027, 594.431, 133.802, 593.036, 293.244, 
493.731, 288.364, 253.773, 380.252, 2025.57, 500.218, 1127.186, 
248.887, 1097.059, 522.202, 193.519, 683.151, 624.277, 289.871, 
625.355, 372.381, 513.871, 1164.912, 1000.163, 1033.844, 815.374, 
1571.724, 1075.799, 922.267, 34.394, 656.606, 205.461, 729.02, 
513.246, 1050.376, 1121.215, 1353.546, 1044.133, 1011.563, 949.681, 
527.63, 2292.579, 1196.44, 3278.845, 522.158, 204.224, 351.753, 
640.973, 1203.779, 975.53, 741.394, 376.48, 144.644, 277.211, 
661.167, 1023.234, 441.863, 540.659, 758.333, 762.133, 726.849, 
699.436)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 21L, 41L, 
61L, 81L, 101L, 121L, 141L, 161L, 181L, 316L, 336L, 356L, 376L, 
396L, 416L, 436L, 456L, 476L, 496L, 516L, 536L, 556L, 576L, 596L, 
616L, 755L, 775L, 795L, 815L, 835L, 855L, 875L, 895L, 915L, 935L, 
955L, 975L, 995L, 1015L, 1035L, 1055L, 1075L, 1095L, 1115L, 1135L, 
1155L, 1175L, 1195L, 1215L, 1235L, 1255L, 1275L, 1295L, 1315L, 
1335L, 1355L, 1375L, 1395L, 1415L, 1435L, 1455L, 1475L, 1495L, 
1515L, 1535L, 1555L, 1575L, 1595L, 1615L, 1635L, 1655L, 1675L, 
1695L, 1715L, 1735L, 1755L, 1775L, 1795L, 1815L, 1835L, 1855L, 
1875L, 1895L, 1915L, 1935L, 1955L, 1975L, 1995L, 2015L, 2035L, 
2055L, 2075L, 2095L, 2115L, 2135L, 2155L, 2175L, 2195L, 2215L, 
2235L, 2255L, 2275L, 2295L, 2315L, 2335L, 2355L, 2375L, 2395L, 
2415L, 2435L, 2455L, 2475L, 2495L, 2515L, 2535L, 2555L, 2575L, 
2595L, 2615L, 2635L, 2655L, 2675L, 2695L, 2715L, 2735L, 2755L, 
2775L, 2795L, 2815L, 2835L, 2855L, 2875L, 2895L, 2915L, 2935L, 
2955L, 2975L, 2995L, 3015L, 3035L, 3055L, 3075L, 3095L, 3115L, 
3135L, 3155L, 3175L, 3195L, 3215L, 3235L, 3255L, 3275L, 3295L, 
3315L, 3335L, 3355L, 3375L, 3395L, 3415L, 3435L, 3455L, 3475L, 
3495L, 3515L, 3535L, 3555L, 3575L, 3595L, 3615L, 3635L, 3655L, 
3675L, 3695L, 3715L, 3735L, 3755L, 3775L, 3795L, 3815L, 3835L, 
3855L, 3875L, 3895L, 3915L, 3935L, 3955L, 3975L, 3995L, 4015L, 
4035L, 4055L, 4075L, 4095L, 4115L, 4135L, 4155L, 4175L, 4195L, 
4215L, 4235L, 4255L, 4275L, 4295L, 4315L, 4335L, 4355L, 4375L, 
4395L, 4415L, 4435L, 4455L, 4475L, 4495L, 4515L, 4535L, 4555L, 
4575L, 4595L, 4615L, 4635L, 4655L))
```

This is the code that I'm working with.

```
  ggplot(size.df, aes(interaction(Tat, Cocaine, sep=" | "), Size, fill=interaction(Drug, Drugcc, sep = " ")))+
  geom_boxplot(color = "black", alpha = 1, outlier.shape = NA, size=.25, position =  position_dodge2(width = 0.75))+
  geom_point(pch = 21, alpha=.65, position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .9))+
  
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = 1)+
  
  labs(y=bquote("Size" ~ (um^2)), x=paste("Tat", "(ng/ul)", " | ", "Cocaine", "(uM)"), fill=paste("Concentrations", "(uM)"))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 15)+
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

I'd like to:

1. Have box plots to follow order: "Control", "EPZ", "Amlexanox",  "Senicapoc"(1, then 5), "Itaconate" (60, then 250), i.e. within each condition, in an increasing numerical value
2. Have the legend in a horizontal order: Control, EPZ 3, Amlexanox 25, Senicapoc 1, Senicapoc 5, etc. Not in the default condition.

I've referenced following: [Link](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776858/reorder-columns-in-boxplots-ggplot2)

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit: I've made a visual order that the legend variables should follow in the figure below.

[image: Example figure for legend]

Comment: Can you check whether the order in the solution works for you

Comment: First, arrange the data frame *before* creating the factor. As for your second concern, set `guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))`. Right now, `nrow = 2`.

Comment: @ThomasBilach `nrow = 2` is there because when I export this graph, the legend gets cut off. Is there anyway to arrange the legend to follow a "Z" shape, instead of what is now: mirrored 'N' shape?

Comment: You could always rearrange the size of the text or the margins to suits your needs. Could you describe Z-shape a bit more?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I've edited the image for clarification of 'Z'-shape. I want the first rows to contain Control, EPZ, Amlexanox; the second row to contain Senicapoc(s), and Itaconate(s) increasing from left to right, if possible.

Comment: You can certainly create a legend with a single row if you specify the proper adjustments. Or, if you want a *row-wise* ordering scheme, use the argument `byrow = TRUE`. I posted a response below to help you visualize this. Hopefully you find the ordering scheme that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to first `arrange` the dataset based on the custom order on both of those columns before converting the `unite`ed column to `factor` with `levels` specified in that order

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

size.df %>%
     unite(Tat, Tat, Cocaine, sep = " | ") %>%
     unite(Drug_cc, Drug, Drugcc, sep= " ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
     arrange(match(Drug, c("Control", "EPZ", "Amlexanox", 
              "Senicapoc", "Itaconate" )), Drugcc) %>% 
     mutate(Drug_cc = factor(Drug_cc, levels = unique(Drug_cc))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Tat, Size, fill = Drug_cc)) +
     geom_boxplot(color = "black", alpha = 1, 
         outlier.shape = NA, size=.25, position =  position_dodge2(width = 0.75))+
    geom_point(pch = 21, alpha=.65, 
       position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .9))+       
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = 1)+       
   labs(y=bquote("Size" ~ (um^2)),
      x=paste("Tat", "(ng/ul)", " | ", "Cocaine", "(uM)"), 
          fill=paste("Concentrations", "(uM)"))+
   theme_bw(base_size = 15)+
   theme(
     legend.position = "top",
     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
     axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
     axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))+
   guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code worked beautifully! How did you approach creating this dataframe? As in, is there anything that I could read up on to solve a similar problem in the future?

Comment: @CeC Thank you for the message.  I used the tidyverse approach to modify the dataset. It would be helpful to go through the vignettes of tidyverse so as to get more information

Comment: @CeC Here is a [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) from which you can get the articles and cheat sheets of tidyverse

Comment: Thank you! Even though I'm somewhat knowledgeable of the individual functions (and the website), I wasn't able to bring them together and apply to the problem. I hope that spending time to working on different projects will better my code manipulation skill. Thanks again for your expertise!

Comment: @CeC It will take some time with practice.  Imagine you are trying to learn a new note on keyboard.  It takes at least some hours to get used to it

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with your second concern, I decided to reproduce your plot to obtain your desired output. Since most of the foundation has already been laid, I recommend selecting @akrun's answer.

The Z-shape you're referring to is a *row-wise* ordering scheme. The legend-matrix defaults to a column-wise fill, and so you must specify `byrow = TRUE` inside of the `guide_legend()` function. Tinkering with the `row = ...` or `col = ...` arguments will not help, as it will *always* column-wise stack your categories. To achieve your desired output, add this code to the very end:

- `guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))`

Here is your legend filled row-wise:

[image: row-wise fill]

And lastly, your plot could still be amended to include a *single* row (i.e., `nrow = 1`). Adjusting the legend's text size or tinkering with `legend.key.width = unit()` inside of `theme()` is something to consider. Standardizing the legend text to `size = 10` and adjusting the key width to 3 `"mm"` produces a reasonably sized legend, though now it's a little less salient. Here is your legend with one row:

[image: singe-row]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now I've learned that the default legend orientation is vertical, and there are specific functions for the presentation of the legend.